# How to create Context object, which is required in calling SQLiteOpenHelper constructor

Tags: sqlite

I am creating some hack kind of thing in existing android code to verify database creation and its accessibility across layers in application.

For this I have modified an existing function of .java file but I am facing an issue while calling constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper.

The signature is `SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)`

And I don't know how to create this Context instance. From googling I am seeing it is being some kind of activity class instance.

What ways are there to create this Context instance? Do we have to have activity class implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android). It shows how to obtain a reference to the current Context object statically.

The gist of it is that you have to store a reference to the context that can be accessed statically from other sections of code.

P.S. You can't really "create" a context. That is something that is provided to you by the Android platform.

Comment: @Amit - glad you found my answer helpful! if this answered your question please upvote or mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call:

```
this.getApplicationContext()
```

from wherever you are trying to create the instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper`.